# How can I route OkHttp request to specific network interface?

Tags: android, http, networking, okhttp, network-interface

What I'm trying to achieve is to bypass mobile/3G connection or at least make it second choice when I try some network request. I need this in order to get smallest possible delay when making HTTP request to the device which is connected to AP on my device.

I've tried making custom SocketFactory where I've explicitely set local address of the wifi network interface (wlan0) and passing it to the OkHttpClient. From the logs/debug I've figured out that OkHttpClient didn't use that local address and routing I've thought it would use but tried to contact proxy (APN setting for 3G connection).

Is there any way to bypass unnecessary 3g call (probably tried to resolve host address)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to build an implementation of OkHttp’s `Dns` interface that uses Android’s [Network](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Network.html) for DNS lookups.

Comment: Thanks, we made a reasonably quick fail+handover from 3G/LTE to WiFi with disabling proxies but will look after your proposal in due time.